# Getting an unknow databse error while trying to connect to my database present in phpmyadminusing xampp

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin, xampp

I am getting the following error:

> Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1049): Unknown database 'sample' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\cab\Ddetailstransfer.php on line 19 UNABLE TO CONNECT

so here is the connection part of my code...

```
<?php
    $firstname=$_POST['firstname'];
    $lastname=$_POST['lastname'];
    $contact=$_POST['contact'];
    $demail=$_POST['email'];
    $duserid=$_POST['duserid'];
    $dpassword=$_POST['dpsw'];
    echo "$firstname";
    echo "$lastname";
    echo "$contact";
    echo "$demail";
    echo "$duserid";
    echo "$dpassword";

    if(!empty($firstname) || !empty($lastname) || !empty($contact) || !empty($demail) || !empty($duserid) || !empty($dpassword))
    {
        $con= mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','sample') or die('UNABLE TO CONNECT');
        mysqli_select_db($con,'cab');          
        $query="INSERT INTO driver(first_name,last_name) values('$firstname','$lastname')";
        $query_run=mysqli_query($con,$query);
    }
```

[database with the name 'cab' is also present in phpmyadmin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/41MQh.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please add the code in your question. Link targets may not be permanent and pictures of code can't be copied for one to answer with edits of your code. Refer to [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) when asking a question.

Comment: try this: `$con= mysqli_connect('localhost','root') or die("Error: " . mysqli_error($con)); mysqli_select_db($con,'sample'); ` (connects and selects db separately)